# What is the UH flag in routing table

Tags: 14.04, iptables, network-bridge, routing

I'm using an Ubuntu machine as a server and it has two network interfaces. One is the `10.10.10.0/ 24` range and the other is `192.168.0.0 /24` range. I was trying to bridge these network interfaces as the second one has internet. I used the Network Connections options by selecting the Share Internet option and it did not work. I undid the changes and instead used a script that enable IP forwarding and added a masquerade option in the IP tables. But now everytime the `10.10.10.0 /24` is started the `192.168.0.0 /24` interface is flagged as `UH` and is unusable until I run a script to remove all default gateways and readd the 192 one. What could be the cause of this and how do I get rid of it? [image: This is the output from IP routing table]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR UH flags in routing tables means:

- U: route is up
- H: this is a route to a single host (and not a network)

The different flags are:

> ```
>  1      RTF_PROTO1       Protocol specific routing flag #1
>  2      RTF_PROTO2       Protocol specific routing flag #2
>  3      RTF_PROTO3       Protocol specific routing flag #3
>  B      RTF_BLACKHOLE    Just discard pkts (during updates)
>  b      RTF_BROADCAST    The route represents a broadcast address
>  D      RTF_DYNAMIC      Created dynamically (by redirect)
>  G      RTF_GATEWAY      Destination requires forwarding by intermediary
>  H      RTF_HOST     Host entry (net otherwise)
>  L      RTF_LLINFO       Valid protocol to link address translation
>  M      RTF_MODIFIED     Modified dynamically (by redirect)
>  R      RTF_REJECT       Host or net unreachable
>  S      RTF_STATIC       Manually added
>  U      RTF_UP       Route usable
>  X      RTF_XRESOLVE     External daemon translates proto to link address
> ```

You will find a discussion on their meaning [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/route-flags/) for example.

Comment: why does it only show up when the 10 network is up and then I cannot access the 192.168.0.1 host until I run those scripts removing the default gateway and readding one.

Comment: I don't really know, what is your IP forwarding script ?

Comment: this occurs as soon as the 10 interface comes up and the 192 is already connected way before I run the scripts.